# Limit of $\frac{\tau^\alpha (n)}{n}$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for all $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\tau^\alpha (n)}{n}=0$$
where $\tau(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$.

I thought that maybe I could use that $$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\log \tau(n))\log(\log n)}{(\log 2)(\log n)} =1 $$ but I didn’t get anywhere by using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(n) = \frac{\tau(n)^a}{n}$ it is a multiplicative function. It satisfies $$f(p^k) = \frac{(k+1)^a}{p^k}, \qquad \lim_{|p^k| \to \infty} f(p^k)=0$$
Let $$C = \prod_{p^k, f(p^k) > 1} f(p^k)$$ which is finite.

> If $n > p^k! $ then $n$ has some prime power factor which is larger than $p^k$.

Thus $$f(n) =\prod_{p^e\|n} f(p^e) \le C \sup_{|p^r| > p^k} f(p^r)$$
and hence $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)=0$$

Comment: Thank you, I just have a question, with $|p^r|$ do you mean the absolute value of $p^r$? If so, why is that necessary?

Comment: It is not, that's just to make clear it is about $p^k \to \infty$, we are considering the increasing sequence of all prime powers, not the one with a fixed $p$ or $k$.

Comment: Alright, that clears it all, thank you!